Django test a custom field in a test model using SqlLite3; cannot disable constraint checking to create database table
I need to write test for a custom field with access to the database.
The code is the following :
class TestMyField (TestCase):
    def SetUpClass(cls):
       super().setUpClass()
       class MyModel(models.Model):
            class Meta:
                app_label = 'test_app'

            hfield = HEnumField(
                enum=MyHEnum)
        setattr(cls, 'MyModel', MyModel)
    def test(self):
       self.MyModel.objects.create(.....)
       self.assert(.....)  

My Problem is to create a database table for this test_model. I intend to do it in the TestMyField class
I Tried  :
from django.db import connections 
db_connection = connections['default']
with db_connection.constraint_checks_disabled():
    with db_connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor :
       schema_editor.create_model(MyModel)`

This causes the following exception:
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: SQLite schema editor cannot be used while foreign key constraint checks are enabled. Make sure to disable them before entering a transaction.atomic() context because SQLite does not support disabling them in the middle of a multi-statement transaction.
I tried using SimpleTestcase for my Test Class instead of TestCase. This causes the following exception
django.test.testcases.DatabaseOperationForbidden: Database queries to 'default' are not allowed in SimpleTestCase subclasses. Either subclass TestCase or TransactionTestCase to ensure proper test isolation or add 'default' to commons.tests.tests_enums_and_fields.TestHEnumField.databases to silence this failure.
Where is the problem. Any Help would be welcomed

The code above passes .Just make sure the TestClass is a unittest.TestCase ad not a TestCase or a SimpleTestCase
